# QGIS fishnet problem

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, vector-grid

I have create a grid in QGIS. But I don't have coordinates, I would like to sketch on the basis of Google satelitte, that uses Pseudo Mercator projection. I tried GRASS `mkgrid`, but something went wrong.

> ERROR: North must be larger than South, and other warnings.

I read many forums about Pseudo Mercator mistake, but I cannot find the solution. What are my options for useable method?

---

[image]

I tried this settings for fishnet

---

The create grid not solving for me, because necessary define number of rows and columns, therefore I need to use mkgrid

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a plain grid (no rotation or other fancy stuff), there is no need to use GRASS `mkgrid`.

Try the QGIS ***Create grid*** algorithm instead.

1. Specify EPSG:3857 - WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator for *Grid CRS*
2. Set the extent

   - using the canvas extent
   - using a layer extent
   - by selecting it on the canvas
   - by just supplying the numbers: **xmin**, **xmax**, **ymin**, **ymax**